# Excel to xml conversion not working for columns with different datatype values starts from number to string

Tags: c#, xml, linq, excel, types

I am facing a problem while reading the excel and writing them to XML using LINQ to XML.

I am having a column name as PinCode which has values like

9999
12
"123"
"20"
"999"
3
While converting the excel to dataset I have the values 9999,12,3. I am not able to retrieve the values in string format.

I dont want to change the formats in excel sheets. Is it possible to change the connectiion string to read all the data in a column irrespective of the datatype of the column

Note:- I tried using IMEX=1 in extended properties it is not working.

Reading the data like this

```
private static OleDbDataReader GetDatafromExcel(OleDbConnection oledbConn)
        {
            OleDbDataReader OledBReader = null;
            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                OleDbCommand oledbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, oledbConn);
                OledBReader = oledbCommand.ExecuteReader();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return OledBReader;
        }
```

Comment: How are you reading the data from the excel spreadsheet? What are you storing the data in once you read it in?  Please post some example code.

Answer (score 1):

Caution - known hack -

For the first record in the Excel spread sheet make it '9999 instead of 9999.  This should treat the values as a string instead of a number.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/86e14302e9.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/86e14302e9.png)

Comment: @Kris I shud not delete the data. is there any other way?